# How to detect various size objects inside image using OpenCV for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, object, opencv, detect

Hello Everyone i am a new to openCV for iPhone and i want to recognize different objects inside any image like pen, pencil, balloon, car, bike etc....

So is it possible ? or is there any tutorial or perfect guide for the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you find a good resource for learning opencv
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCVBooks

You can consider using pattern matching. but then you need a pattern for each object you want to detect, and the pattern matching ist not orientation-invariant. so your pattern only works for object that have the same rotation in the image. of course you could rotate that pattern and perform patternmatching again. but that's quite computative expensive.

so another approach is blob detection,
check out http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib
and watch some videos on youtube on "blob detection opencv example", you will find many examples that show what it does. with blob detection you can identify where different objects are but not if it is a pencil, or a ballon ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply i really appreciate this but i am looking for some sample code.

Comment: @PratikMistry Hi...do you have sample code of it.I am looking for sample code. Please help me

Comment: your both URL is not working